# Check if attribute exists in directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to check if an attribute exists in a directive and I don't know how to do that, can anyone help? this is probably simple but I am new to angular

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular.module('app').directive('home', home);

var strVar="";
strVar += "<home show-text=vm.text></home>" 

function home() {
return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: strVar,
        scope: {

            showText: "="
        },
        controller: HomeController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
};
};

HomeController.$inject = ['$scope','$rootScope', '$timeout','$sce'];
function HomeController($scope,$rootScope,$timeout,$sce) {
if(vm.showText == “undefined”)
{
//Run some code
}


})();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (angular.isUndefined($scope.showText)) {
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: is that checking to see if the attribute exists in the directive?

Comment: I got this to work after I changed showText: "=" to showText: "&"

Answer (score 1):

on the directive object change the scope object to
 `scope: { showText: "=?" },`
the '?' is making an attribute optional,
then in the controller check if the attribute exists with `angular.isUndefined(vm.showText)` or with `typeof vm.showText === 'undefined'`

for more info check out [angular 1.7.x - Error: $compile:nonassign
Non-Assignable Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/nonassign)

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question but there is another way to check if attribute exists

```
if(angular.isDefined(vm.content.title)){ //do something}
```